# Using provided scope with Android Studio and Gradle (0.5.8+ only)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Using provided scope stopped working in android studio 0.5.8 for java modules.

For example, my Java module uses some classes that are required from Android...(bad I know, but issue exists with any kind of provided lib). Project compiles and runs fine but IDE shows provided classes as red:

[image]

- Everything worked fine before 0.5.8 of android studio.
- Intellisense does not work anymore....I feel like a savage coding without autocompletion
- Filed a bug, where you can see details of the gradle file https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69481&thanks=69481&ts=1399651923[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAUMW.png)

I want to believe this is a common setup, has anyone run into this and come up with any solutions?

Comment: It's possible you're hitting a bug in the Android Gradle plugin; there are some issues we're tracking down. Could you try disabling incremental dex (see docs at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) and doing a clean rebuild? If that doesn't work, you could try clearing your Gradle caches (.gradle directory in both your home directory and your project root) and rebuilding.

Comment: @ScottBarta thanks, but no luck on both suggestions.

Comment: @ScottBarta - do you think this will be fixed soon?